# How can I name a fully-qualified type using a variable?

Tags: php

If I have a class name in `$name`, how can I create an object of type `\folder\$name`? Ideally I'd like to interpolate the `$name` so that I can create the object with just a single line of code.

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$obj = new \folder\$name();
```

Comment: Don't press the enter key...

Comment: This question's title is _really_ poor; it doesn't even begin to talk about the actual problem. Obviously we can create objects in one line (we do it all the time) — the title should reflect the specifics of _this_ scenario that make such an act difficult.

Comment: Hopefully that's improved it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is youre trying to use a variable as part of a FQCN. You cannot do that. The FQCN can be a variable itself like:

```
$fqcn = '\folder\classname';
$obj = new $fqcn();
```

Or you can delcare the namespace at the top of the file:

```
namespace folder;
$fqcn = 'classname';
$obj = new $fqcn;
```

Or if the file belongs to another namespace you can `use` the class to "localize" it:

```
namespace mynamespace;
use folder\classname;

$fqcn = 'classname';
$obj = new $fqcn();
```

A more concrete example of something i assume to be similar to what you are trying to do:

```
namespace App\WebCrawler;

// any local uses of the File class actually refer to 
// \App\StorageFile instead of \App\WebCrawler\File
use App\Storage\File;

// if we didnt use the "as" keyword here we would have a conflict
// because the final component of our storage and cache have the same name
use App\Cache\File as FileCache;

class Client {
// the FQCN of this class is \App\WebCrawler\Client
   protected $httpClient;

   protected $storage;

   protected $cache

   static protected $clients = array(
       'symfony' => '\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client',
       'zend' => '\Zend_Http_Client',
   );

   public function __construct($client = 'symfony') {
       if (!isset(self::$clients[$client])) {
          throw new Exception("Client \"$client\" is not registered.");
       }

       // this would be the FQCN referenced by the array element
       $this->httpClient = new self::$clients[$client]();

       // because of the use statement up top this FQCN would be
       // \App\Storage\File
       $this->storage = new File();

       // because of the use statement this FQCN would be 
       // \App\Cache\File
       $this->cache = new FileCache();

   }

   public static function registerHttpClient($name, $fqcn) {
       self::$clients[$name] = $fqcn;
   }
}
```

You can read in more detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: use \folder\classname; syntax error, unexpected '\', expecting '('

Comment: You dont use the leading the backslash with a `use` statement it should be: `use folder\classname;` ... exactly how i typed it in my answer...

Comment: I can use a "use" in class?

Comment: No... you use them at the top of the file, not in the body of the class. But you shoudl only have one file per class anyhow.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. "use" is not suitable for me, I'm calling from 20 different classes controler and I are at the beginning of the file list them:-(

Comment: Thats not totally uncommon... though its a sign that your design is bad if you have that many outside dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
new \folder\$arr[0];
```

and not

```
new \folder\$arr[0]();
```

Also, I'm not too familiar with PHP, and I've never see this syntax before. What I suggest is:

```
namespace \folder;
$obj = new $arr[0];
```

I'm not sure if you can do it with just one line and without namespaces.

Comment: are you able to debug your program using the back-end? Where exactly is the error?

Comment: using namespace \folder;
Syntax error, unexpected 'EOF', expecting 'identifier'